# Comando para seleccionar valor en base de datos SQL desde Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sql-server

tengo un script de python cuyp propósito es seleccionar un valor "a" de una columna "a", donde la columna "b" tenga un valor "b". Hay un error en la sintaxis pero no logro ubicarlo, si alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal, por favor dígamelo. dejo el código:

```
conn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=PROYECTO\SQLEXPRESS; UID=PROYECTO\Baelca; Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor1=conn.cursor()
cursor1.execute('SELECT  Valor FROM Valores WHERE Nombre=Puerto ')
results=cursor1.fetchall()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Mensaje de error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
> Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Puerto'. (207)
> (SQLExecDirectW)")

Comment: `WHERE Nombre="Puerto"` tal vez?

Comment: Hola @CandidMoe Ya lo intenté, el mismo problema, el mismo mensaje de error. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: @CandidMoe Es posible que, a diferencia de Python, las cadenas en sql se escriban usando comillas simples (eso pasa con postgresql). carlos arraez, si el puerto es una cadena, escribe `where Nombre='puerto'`, si es un número, no uses las comillas.

Comment: Hola @DanteS., no funciona. Lo que hace es que cierra el string antes de Puerto y lo vuelve a abrir despues. Creando un mensaje de error que dice que se omitió una coma.

Comment: Cambia las comillas externas por comillas dobles.

Comment: `cursor1.execute("SELECT  Valor FROM Valores WHERE Nombre='Puerto' ")` me da el error: **pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator. (402) (SQLExecDirectW)')**

Comment: haz uso de la cadena formateada o sea: `""" 
select valor
from valores
where nombre = "puerto"
  """ `

suponiendo que puerto es un valor y no una columna.

Comment: Está solucionado el problema planteado en la pregunta. Ahora tiene otro problema: no puede usar "=" para comparar textos con varchar.

Comment: `"""  select valor from valores where cast(nombre  as nvarchar(max) = "puerto"   """`

Comment: cual es la estructura de la base de datos???

Comment: a mi me parece que la columna nisiquiera existe...

Comment: tal vez **cursor1.execute( "SELECT * FROM Valores WHERE Nombre='Puerto' " )**, ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para los que tengan el mismo problema. Al final la respuesta me la dieron en los comentarios de la primera pregunta. El código corre bien y quedó así:

```
cursor1.execute("SELECT Valor FROM Valores WHERE cast(Nombre  as nvarchar(max)) = 'Puerto' ")
```

Answer (score 0):

El error se produce porque el valor "Puerto" está sin comillas, lo cual hace que el servidor SQL lo interprete como un nombre de columna en lugar de un valor de cadena.

Para arreglar el problema, simplemente debes agregar comillas simples alrededor de "Puerto" en la sentencia SQL, de la siguiente manera:

```
cursor1.execute("SELECT Valor FROM Valores WHERE Nombre='Puerto'")
```

Así el servidor SQL reconocerá que "Puerto" es un valor de cadena y no un nombre de columna. Saludos!

Comment: Hola Ulises, gracias por tu respuesta. El problema es que ahora, la terminal me arroja este error: **pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator. (402) (SQLExecDirectW)')
PS C:\Users\Baelca\Documents\archivos (14-2-23)-1> **

Comment: El error indica que estás tratando de comparar dos tipos de datos incompatibles: `text` y `varchar`, usando el operador = en una consulta SQL. Esto puede ocurrir cuando la columna que estás comparando en la tabla tiene el tipo de datos `text`, que es un tipo de datos obsoleto, mientras que el valor que estás comparando es una cadena de caracteres `varchar`.

Para corregir el error, puedes convertir la columna de tipo text a un tipo de datos compatible, como `nvarchar(max)`. Puedes hacerlo utilizando la función `CAST` en la consulta SQL.

Comment: Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo: `cursor1.execute("SELECT Valor FROM Valores WHERE CAST(Nombre AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) = 'Puerto'")
` En este caso, la consulta convierte la columna Nombre de tipo `text` a tipo `nvarchar(max)` mediante la función `CAST`, para que pueda ser comparada con la cadena de caracteres `Puerto`.

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.